# Core Data Cocoa Application with command line interface

Tags: macos, core-data, command-line, osx-lion

I want to develop a Cocoa Application with a command line interface. Application makes use of Core Data to persist data.

Is it possible to share Core Data model among both modes?

Edit: I want to let the user use both command line and GUI as same application with same data. How to achieve this?

Edit 2: This happened long time back,but I thought it is good to update how I resolved the issue.

As it was a must have requirement to share data among both applications I stored the data in an sqlite backed Core Data in a fixed file location. Then used the same thing for both GUI and command line application. I thought there would be a case of thread safety, didn't write any specific code for it. Even when both applications were operated simultaneously, there was no data corruption.

Answer (score 2):

The MVC pattern is made to let your model work with no dependency of its representation.

So, if you do it correctly, there is no matter, if you work with graphical interface, or command-line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm familiar with MVC pattern, but my concern is how to share the same data among two different targets of same project?